# External Web App Authentication from Salesforce

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, salesforce

I am trying to build a Salesforce App Integration to a SAAS product we own. (say www.ABC.com). The app would have a simple Apex page to fetch files from Salesforce Objects and upload them on ABC.com.

For this to work, I want the users on salesforce to be registered users on ABC.com. They should be able to login into ABC.com from SFDC. However, I have a few concerns

- OAuth - Although SFDC has this capability, I do not want to implement an Oauth Provider service on ABC.com.
- Signed Request Authentication - Since, I want SFDC users to have an account on ABC.com, this strategy may not be helpful. Please correct me if you think I am wrong.
- There would be a simple login apex page on SFDC which logs them in. ABC.com is then embedded into an iframe in the next view.

Any ideas on managing the session and cookies? Do I have to store the cookies in order to have a long lived connection to ABC.com so that users do not have to login every time they use the app. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement and chose to use a signed request when calling my iframe.
When receiving the signed request, I validated that the request came from Salesforce and was signed by the shared secret.
You can then use a convention of mapping between SF users and abc.com users. For example, identical email account.
If so, you log in the user in abc.com.